# Delaying bullets with reload function

Tags: java

Hi i'm currently confused on how to add a timer into my program to add a delay in between shooting bullets, and timing a reload function. This is my current code to shoot a bullet where the mouse is located at when I click E. I want to add a delay to this and a reload function on top of it.

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keyPressed[e.getKeyCode()] = true;

    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_E){
        double xVel = mouseX - (player.x+player.width/2-cameraX);
        double yVel = mouseY - (player.y-cameraY);
        double ratio = Math.sqrt(xVel*xVel+yVel*yVel)/10;
        xVel /= ratio;
        yVel /= ratio;
        lasers.add(new Laser(player.x+player.width/2,player.y,10,10,xVel,yVel));
        //System.out.println("Laser added at "+(player.x+player.width/2)+","+player.y);
        }
}
```

This is called from my Laser class.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Laser {
double x, y;
int width, height;
double horizVel, vertVel;
boolean debug = false;

public Laser(int x, int y, int width, int height, double horizVel, double vertVel) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.horizVel = horizVel;
    this.vertVel = vertVel;
}

public void draw(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    if (debug) {
        g.drawString("horizVel=" + horizVel, x + width + 3, y);
    }
}

public void update() {
    x += horizVel;
    y += vertVel;
}

public static int getHeight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static int getWidth() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

My 1st question is how to implement a timer to my program which will cause a delay between shots. From what I believe I'd have to have a while(True) statement when pressing e to check when the timer is over.

My 2nd question is on how to add a reload timer which tracks the amount of bullets fired, creates a delay "while your reloading" so that you can't fire while this is happening.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

System.currentTimeMillis() will return the current time in milliseconds

so if you do

```
long pastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long timeElapsed = currentTime-pastTime;



// I would control both the reloading time and delay between firing 
// time with two separate variables


if(bulletsleft>0){ //Not out of ammo
     if( reloadTimer<=0 && bulletDelay<=0){ //delays 
         fireShot();}
    }
else{
    reload();


}
```

This obviously doesn't give a full solution to your questions but is at least one way of thinking about it

Comment: Thanks, i'm still struggling to understand on how I would do that. I slightly understand how that works with the if and else statement but i don't understand how I would control the delay simple because I don't know how to use time.